# Placing a component below UITextView and size to fit

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` that must keep a width of say: 100px but the height can grow;  but the height should only be enough to fit the contents.  Right below the `UITextView` I want to display an image.

Is there a control the auto adjust or do I have to code all this myself?

for example:

case 1: the height of `UITextView` is 200px then I want my `UIImageView` to go at 201px (y)
case 2: the height of `UITextView` is 300px then I want my `UIImageView` to go at 301px (y)

Comment: you can use autoresizingMask to make it change automatically,but it may not be exactly 201px
otherwise you can overwrite setFrame to change UIImageView size

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you'll first need to use the `sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode:` (or any of the sizeWithFont... selectors) selector on `NSString` to measure your string (I'm assuming you're not using an attributed string) and then set the `UITextView`'s frame to match the size.

After you have that frame, you can place your `UIImageView` directly below it.